# How to change Picker negative button text independently from OS settings

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, localization, xamarin.android

I have an app only in English language, but my phone's OS is in Spanish. I have added a `Picker` to my page and if I tap it to change it's value, I see that cancel button text is in Spanish. I want to show this button in English. I'm using Xamarin.Forms because it's easier for me to develop with it, but I just need to know how I can make this change **only in Android**. I tried changing the culture in `OnCreate()` method in the `MainActivity`, but it doesn't work (running on debug and release).

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Then I tried with Android specific code (again in `OnCreate()` method in the `MainActivity`):

```
Java.Util.Locale.Default = new Java.Util.Locale("en");
```

But it doesn't work. The text of the button is still in Spanish. In this case I want to change an specific text, but there is no public property that gives me access to change it (i.e. picker.CancelButtonText). I want to display "Cancel" instead of "Cancelar". Do you know how can I change this text?

[image: Picker displaying Spanish text]

I've checked the [PickerRender.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/PickerRenderer.cs) file and I found this code:

```
var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
builder.SetView(layout);
builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");
builder.SetNegativeButton(global::Android.Resource.String.Cancel, (s, a) =>
{
    ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
    // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
    // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
    Control?.ClearFocus();
    _dialog = null;
});
```

`global::Android.Resource.String.Cancel` is a `int` constant, so I can't change it. Do you know you if there is access to the negative button text?

Thank you,
Jon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to set the text on the negative button. I created `CustomPicker` and a `CustomPickerRenderer`:

**CustomPicker.cs** (nothing special):

```
public class CustomPicker : Picker {}
```

**CustomPickerRenderer.cs** (inherited from [`Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/PickerRenderer.cs) and copying some methods from it with a few changes):

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Widget;
using RendererTest.Droid.Renderers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(RendererTest.Controls.CustomPicker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]
namespace RendererTest.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomPickerRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer
    {
        AlertDialog _dialog;
        TextColorSwitcher _textColorSwitcher;

        public CustomPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        // This method is necessary to set the OnClickListener, copied removing base.OnElementChanged(e); line
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            if (e.OldElement != null)
                ((INotifyCollectionChanged)e.OldElement.Items).CollectionChanged -= RowsCollectionChanged;

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                ((INotifyCollectionChanged)e.NewElement.Items).CollectionChanged += RowsCollectionChanged;
                if (Control == null)
                {
                    EditText textField = CreateNativeControl();
                    textField.Focusable = false;
                    textField.Clickable = true;
                    textField.Tag = this;
                    textField.InputType = InputTypes.Null;
                    textField.SetOnClickListener(PickerListener.Instance);
                    _textColorSwitcher = new TextColorSwitcher(textField.TextColors);
                    SetNativeControl(textField);
                }
                UpdatePicker();
                UpdateTextColor();
            }
        }

        // This method is necessary to change negative button text.
        void OnClick()
        {
            Picker model = Element;
            if (_dialog == null)
            {
                using (var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context))
                {
                    builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");
                    string[] items = model.Items.ToArray();
                    builder.SetItems(items, (s, e) => ((IElementController)model).SetValueFromRenderer(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, e.Which));

                    builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (o, args) => { }); // Changing negative button text

                    ((IElementController)Element).SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, true);

                    _dialog = builder.Create();
                }
                _dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                _dialog.DismissEvent += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    (Element as IElementController)?.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
                    _dialog.Dispose();
                    _dialog = null;
                };

                _dialog.Show();
            }
        }

        void RowsCollectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdatePicker();
        }

        void UpdatePicker()
        {
            Control.Hint = Element.Title;

            if (Element.SelectedIndex == -1 || Element.Items == null)
                Control.Text = null;
            else
                Control.Text = Element.Items[Element.SelectedIndex];
        }

        void UpdateTextColor()
        {
            _textColorSwitcher?.UpdateTextColor(Control, Element.TextColor);
        }

        // The listener is changed to work with CustomPickerRenderer
        class PickerListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnClickListener
        {
            #region Statics

            public static readonly PickerListener Instance = new PickerListener();

            #endregion

            public void OnClick(global::Android.Views.View v)
            {
                var renderer = v.Tag as CustomPickerRenderer; // Work with my renderer
                renderer?.OnClick();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also it is necessary to add the [`TextColorSwitcher`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/TextColorSwitcher.cs) class to the source code.

Answer (score 1):

> global::Android.Resource.String.Cancel is a int constant, so I can't change it. Do you know you if there is access to the negative button text?

You are in the right direction, but unfortunately there is currently no way for user to access the `AlertDialog` of `Picker`, thus there is no way to customize or custom localize the `Cancel` button text.

The only option I can see now is to create your own `Picker` control using custom renderer and build the `AlertDialog` yourself, then you can get the button through `AlertDialog.GetButton`.

Comment: I am trying to create a CustomPicker and CustomPickerRenderer with very simple implementations: `public class CustomPicker : Picker { }` and `public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer { public CustomPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }}`. The renderer has this annotation above he namespace statement: `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(RendererTest.Controls.CustomPicker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]`. But the behavior is totally different from each other. Why do they render different if I only inherit from the same classes?

Comment: There are two `PickerRenderer` , one is `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PickerRenderer` the other is `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer` Xamarin.Forms use the later one by default. Please make sure you are using the same one.

Comment: Besides, by creating a custom renderer using `PickerRenderer` won't fulfill your requirement. As the `AlertDialog` is defined inside the `PickerRenderer`, by inheriting it won't have access to change it. You need to inherit from `ViewRenderer<Picker, EditText>` to create a totally new Picker.

Comment: Thank you again! I had problems creating a renderer from `ViewRenderer<Picker, EditText>` because `PickerRenderer` implementation has an internal method overrided, I couldn't implement it (`OnFocusChangeRequested()`) and I want the same behavior. But I managed to create the renderer from `PickerRenderer` copying `OnElementChanged()`, `OnClick()` (changing `SetNegativeButton()` statement), `RowsCollectionChanged()`, `UpdatePicker()` and `UpdateTextColor` methods and also `PickerListener` (changed to work with `CustomPickerRenderer`) and `TextColorSwitcher` classes.

Comment: I don't know what is better: accept your answer or send my answer with full code.

Comment: I didn't try it, but when inheriting from `PickerRenderer`, by overriding  `OnElementChanged` without calling `base.OnElementChanged` might works for this scenario.  So, you can have try of that.

Comment: You are right, I removed `base.OnElementChanged(e);` line and it works fine!